# Zero items in typedQuery.resultList()

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I need to get from DB items in a date range ("created"). Query is correct (i check it in HeidiSQL) and select right rows from DB, but typedQuery.resultList() always has 0 items.

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<CurrencyConvertionRate> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(CurrencyConvertionRate.class);

Root<CurrencyConvertionRate> root = criteriaQuery.from(CurrencyConvertionRate.class);

List<Predicate> criteria = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

<Timestamp>get(created)={}", criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.<Timestamp>get("created"), dateFrom).toString());
log.debug("criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.<Timestamp>get(created), dateTo={}", criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.<Timestamp>get("created"), dateTo).toString());
log.debug("root.get(currencyCode).in(currencyList)={}", root.get("currencyCode").in(currencyList).toString());

criteria.add(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.<Timestamp>get("created"), dateFrom));
criteria.add(criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.<Timestamp>get("created"), dateTo));
criteria.add(root.get("currencyCode").in(currencyList));
CriteriaQuery<CurrencyConvertionRate> select = criteriaQuery.select(root);
select.where(criteriaBuilder.and(criteria.toArray(new Predicate[0])));

TypedQuery<CurrencyConvertionRate> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(select);
return typedQuery.getResultList();
```

Comment: Post the JPQL that this equates to, and the SQL executed. Also FWIW : Your "select" is the same object as "criteriaQuery" so don't see the point in a new variable.

Comment: SELECT ID, CREATED, <some other columns> FROM CPP_CURRENCY_CONVERTION_RATE WHERE (((CREATED >= ?) AND (CREATED <= ?)) AND (CURRENCY_CODE IN (?)))
        bind => [3 parameters bound]

Comment: And a executed query:

SELECT ID, CREATED, <some other columns> FROM CPP_CURRENCY_CONVERTION_RATE WHERE (((CREATED >= '2016-04-14 00:00:00') AND (CREATED <= '2016-04-20 00:00:00')) AND (CURRENCY_CODE IN ('EUR','USD','GBP')));
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 8  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.000 sec. */

Comment: What are parameters bound to the query, and what is the currencyList exactly?  Turn on logging to get the bound parameters, and show what you are using for currencyList and what it contains.  My guess is the 'in' currencyList is being bound as an object instead of broken up into 3 ('EUR','USD','GBP') components you are using in your SQL query manually.

Comment: This code is punishing to read. Using some well named variables would really help. You won't have the distracting type parameters. And then you could use the variables in your logging statements.